# Spring's component-scan don't find class in external jar

Tags: java, spring

I'm new in Spring, I would "autowired" my class interface to its implement class in external jar.

This is a jar's code:

```
@Component
public class MongoSpring implements IMongo {

     MongoSpring() throws UnknownHostException {
        System.out.println("mongo template builder");
    }

    @Required
    public void save()  {
        System.out.println("mongo template save");
    }
}
```

The class interface:

```
@Component
public interface IMongo {
    void save();
}
```

The class where I make the autowire

```
@Component
public class Core {
    @Autowired
    public IMongo db ;

    public void run () {

        log.info("core ");
        db.save();
    }
```

The main class

```
public class MongoApp {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

         context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("path.xml");

         Core c = (Core)context.getBean(Core.class);
         c.run();
      }
}
```

The bean file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

        <context:annotation-config />
        <context:component-scan base-package="org.spring.mongodb.example" />

    </bean>
</beans>
```

When I run it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'core': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public org.spring.mongodb.example.IMongo org.spring.mongodb.example.Core.db; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.spring.mongodb.example.IMongo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

[...]

What can I do? I'm using spring 3.2.0 with STS

---

I have removed @Component from interface and @Require but doesn't change. The Jar file is in classpath and the package is correct. Thank you

Comment: What's the package for MongoSpring

Comment: basically the class with package `org.spring.mongodb.example` was not found. Check if that package exists in the classpath and contains the relevant class.

Comment: I see two things that should be fixed, but I'm not sure if either of them would cause your problem.  First thing is that you shouldn't put `@Component` on your interface--Spring can only create beans out of non-abstract classes.  Second, `@Required` is meant to be used on property setter methods.  What are you trying to solve by putting it on your `save()` method?